# What is the best approach to do a PCA analysis to distinguish between two groups?

Tags: r, differential-expression, pca

I have two samples A and B and I do have an RNAseq for both of them. Inside each file (for A and B) I do have a set of FPKMs that give me a fold change for each gene (sample vs control). It looks somewhat like that:

```
gen_name grp01 grp02 grp03 grp04 fold_change
gene1    10    10    5     5     2
gene2    11    11    11    11    1
gene3    5     5     10    10    0.5
gene4    ...
```

for sample A
and, say

```
gen_name grp05 grp06 grp07 grp08 fold_change
gene1    100   100   5     5     20
gene2    110   110   110   110   1
gene3    5     5     100   100   0.05
gene4    ...
```

for sample B

I need to show with PCA that, foe example, gene1 is sample B is much more overexpressed than in sample A, same for gene3, but it looks like gene2 is not very interesting.

What data must be put in PCA analysis?

Comment: Using a package is the best approach. Scanpy is popular right now. I do this stuff via first principles, so my advice isn't cool here. Anyway, I'd combine all data into one dataframe, minus log-fold change. I assume log fold change is the opposing sample? The data must have a column to identify A genes from B genes, or denoted within the gene name. PCA does not give gene by gene comparisons, it will be cluster by cluster. Interpreting each clusters is done independently (by mapping the log-fold-change), i.e. what is clustering together and that cluster represents a cohesive expression group.

Comment: The alternative is DEG analysis, gene by gene - which you've already done.

Comment: Thank you. I want to show that A is different from B based on an expression of gene1 and gene3 (in this test experiment). I want to do this in R but scanpy is a python package. Is there any way to use ```prcomp()``` ?